# Run RSelenium on Raspberry pi using headless phantomjs browser

Tags: r, raspberry-pi, phantomjs, rselenium

I am attempting to move an rselenium script to a raspberry pi 3. Before going into and editing the script, I am testing if it is possible to run rselenium on the pi by just attempting simple open and navigate commands.

R version is 3.6.1.

I started trying to use Chromium and Firefox, downloading chrome driver and gecko, but was unable to open a browser from the command line. So I moved onto a headless browser: phantomjs.

Current script is:

```
library(RSelenium)

pJS <- wdman::phantomjs(pjs_cmd = "phantomjs-raspberrypi/bin/phantomjs") 

remDr <- remoteDriver(browser = c("phantomjs"))

remDr$open

remDr$navigate("https://www.google.com/ncr")

remDr$getTitle()[[1]]

remDr$close

pJS$stop()
```

Searching has led me to several tutorials but all written with the now defunct phantom function and dated at least 3 years ago.

Error message currently output is:

```
Error in checkError(res)
undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

A search of the web hasn't helped in interpreting this error.

I suspect I am missing a dependency that enables the pi to use phantomjs but I cannot find guidelines or package readme guides that are pi specific or from more recent than several updated versions previously.

At this point I am simply looking to test whether this task is possible on the pi by opening and executing a simple collect title command. Are there any users who have used a raspberry pi in this manner that could provide a list of required dependencies or a reproducible example of activating a phantom browser?

Comment: I'm sure I don't know, but are you aware of the R library named `decapitated`?

Comment: I hadn't until now but seems promising. Can it be instructed to enter commands and interact with websites in the same way as selenium?

Comment: I have same problem with Rselenium and chromium. I gave up looking for a solution in R and switched to python using selenium for the automation portion but still use R for the rest of the function. You can use reticulate package, system(), or processx package to run the python script... so much smoother and easier, much more support too online